# Changing lines to column in R

Tags: r, reshape

I have a data frame like this:

```
Month Site1 Site2 Site3
Jan    5     6     8
Feb    2     3     4
Mar    8     2     2
```

I want to change it to

```
Site Jan Feb Mar
Site1 5   2   8
Site2 6   3   2
Site3 8   4   2
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `recast` from `library(reshape2)`

```
library(reshape2)
dfN <- recast(df1, id.var='Month', variable~Month, value.var='value')
```

If we need to order the columns

```
cbind(Site=dfN[,1], dfN[-1][order(match(names(dfN)[-1], month.abb))])
#    Site Jan Feb Mar
#1 Site1   5   2   8
#2 Site2   6   3   2
#3 Site3   8   4   2
```

---

A faster option would be `melt/dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(df1), id.var='Month', 
    variable.name='Site')[, Month:= factor(Month,
    levels=month.abb)], Site~Month, value.var='value')
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
`row.names<-`(cbind(Site= colnames(df1)[-1], 
    setNames(as.data.frame(t(df1[-1])), df1[,1])), NULL)
```

Comment: thank you it works but it arrange the column with Alphabetic order

Comment: @Madamespring  Changed the order now

Comment: I wonder what a suitable [definition of harassment might be](http://i.imgur.com/rueBJ1z.png).... My comment? Or pressurizing new users to question their voting patterns....

Answer (score 0):

A base R alternative would be something like:

```
reshape(cbind(mydf[1], stack(mydf[-1])), idvar = "ind", 
        timevar = "Month", direction = "wide")
##     ind values.Jan values.Feb values.Mar
## 1 Site1          5          2          8
## 4 Site2          6          3          2
## 7 Site3          8          4          2
```

All that is left is cleaning up the column names....

Answer (score -1):

Would a simple transpose also do the trick in your case?

```
> bla <- read.table("test.df", header=T, row.names=1, sep='\t')
> bla
    Site1 Site2 Site3
Jan     5     6     8
Feb     2     3     4
Mar     8     2     2
> t(bla)
      Jan Feb Mar
Site1   5   2   8
Site2   6   3   2
Site3   8   4   2
```

Instead of using reshape, this may be a more simple and straight forward solution.

Comment: Well it's rather hidden in the last option. I didn't see it and maybe the very plain option does the job either...

Comment: True. The output doesn't fit completely. This skipped my attention.